# How to change selected tab in TabView from another class?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to switch a tab in TabView based upon received Push notification. My TabView looks like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
```

Receiving a Push notification and trying to change a tab:

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        (window?.rootViewController?.view as? ContentView)?.selection = 2
```

This gives an error - `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Int'`. How can I fix that?

Comment: I would suggest adding tags to your tab items on the `TabView` that way you can access the State of the selection property and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but tags are added but I'm not sure how it's related to the error I posted. Basically the problem is with struct View being immutable as far as I understand.

Comment: I'd try to put your `selection` var in an Observable Object (view model or the main environment object).  There, it will be mutable and will trigger your ContentView to update when it is changed.